# Redis MSET equivalent for a SET or LIST?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, booksleeve

I'm writing a C# application that interfaces with REDIS (via a C# REDIS client interface, such as ServiceStack / BookSleeve).

I'm looking for advice in how to most efficiently multi-save two concurrent lists of keys & values into co-ordinated sets. Some of the keys will be duplicated, at which point I want to simply add the corresponding value to the set.  The MSET command allows for adding multiple key / value pairs, but I'm targeting sets containing the values.

My research so far has pointed me at pipelining multiple SADD commands for each distinct grouping of keys & values, but I was curious if there was a more efficient method.

Comment: It cannot be more efficient than pipelining one SADD command per set. And if you have too many items in a set, you may have to split the command in smaller pieces.

Comment: @DidierSpezia I figured as much. I guess it's a reasonably specific requirement which doesn't quite fit into a native command.

Comment: `SADD` is varadic from 2.4 onwards - you should only need one `SADD` per set; is that what you are asking?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm looking for a way to add multiple sets, atomically if possible, based on 2 lists of strings (keys & values).  I've settled for mapping the lists into a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` (key being the set name) and pipelining SADD commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled for mapping the lists into a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` (key being the set name) and pipelining SADD commands.

Any further suggestions very welcome.